# Javascript custom function error

Tags: jquery, arguments, javascript

```
function classChanger(path,changeClass,duration){
    $(path).removeClass(changeClass);
    $(this).addClass(changeClass);
)};

$('.flightDetails .option').classChanger('.flightDetails .option','selected',300);
```

I am trying to create reusable function.
Console log: **TypeError: $(".flightDetails .option").classChanger is not a function**

Appreciate your help and time :)

Answer (score 5):

You have to declare your `classChanger` on the jQuery prototype:

```
$.fn.classChanger = function(path, changeClass, duration) {
    $(path).removeClass(changeClass);
    return this.addClass(changeClass);
};
```

For more info, read the [jQuery Plugin Authoring Guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

---

**Update:** As pointed out in the comments, if you intend for `path` and the selector to always be identical, you should forgo `path` completely, and just use `this` throughout.

Since you haven't specified exactly what it is you're trying to do, I'm assuming you want to remove the class, then wait for the `duration` specified and then re-add the class. If that's the case, here's some sample code:

```
$.fn.classChanger = function(changeClass, duration) {
    var $this = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.addClass(changeClass);
    }, duration);

    return this.removeClass(changeClass);
};

$('.flightDetails .option').classChanger('selected', 300);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ur7SN/

Comment: Why not just use remove the `path` argument entirely and use `this` instead of rebuilding an identical jQuery object with `$(path)`? (Admittedly, the OP doesn't say if `path` should ever differ from the selector, but I've got a strong hunch they're always the same.)

Comment: @apsillers - Because the OP has not specified what he's trying to achieve here. In his example, he's using identical selectors, but that might not always be the case.

Comment: True enough.  Personally, I'd provide it as an addendum to the answer (*"if you intend that `path` and the selector should always be identical..."*, but I suppose my comment is addendum enough. (In any case, +1.)

Comment: @apsillers - If it's always the same, then this piece of code does absolutely nothing. It first removes the class, then adds it back in...

Comment: True!  I concede that original suspicion is becoming increasingly less likely. Perhaps, though, this is an incomplete implementation, considering the unused `duration` argument. My advice here is absolutely based on nothing but speculation.

Comment: @apsillers - I've added an addendum, but I'm still shooting in the dark.